# HTML text is not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm not a web developer but I'm trying to make a small edit where numbers in a td tag are centered, here's my code:

```
<td align="center" valign="middle">1</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle">5</td>
```

Here's my result:

[image]

I'd like the numbers to align with the rest of the table, how would I do this? Thank you for reading

Comment: Post the code for the other 2 rows in your image

Comment: If any of the posted answers solved your question, please accept it, if not, let us know that we can do to find you one that does

Answer (score 2):

Either you want them centered, or you want them to align with the rest of the table. Since the cells of the rest of the table are left-aligned, you can't have both without changing the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a padding-right in your css to move them to the left just enough to get them in the middle